# Setting additionalLoginParams with auth v2

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I've followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux) to configure access to my backend app, but I use Node backend and React frontend. However I'm unable to perform the step [Configure App Service to return a usable access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux#configure-app-service-to-return-a-usable-access-token). I get the error `"Cannot execute the request for site x because the site is running on auth version v2."`. To handle this I tried instead editing the sheet authsettingsV2, and I believe I found that the property `properties.identityProviders.azureActiveDirectory.login.loginParameters` in v2 equals `properties.additionalLoginParams` in v1 as editing this v2 property according to the tutorial shows the desired property in the v1 authsettings sheet.

However accessing my frontend app with this setting I get the error `AADSTS901002: The 'resource' request parameter is not supported.` before even being able to enter my credentials.

I've also tried without the `additionalLoginParams` setting completely, this gives me the error `{"code":401,"message":"IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: '[PII is hidden]'. \nkid: '[PII is hidden]'. \nExceptions caught:\n '[PII is hidden]'.\ntoken: '[PII is hidden]'."}` on the API call, and upon inspecting my token, I find that the audience is the Microsoft Graph API. But I guess that is expected with this setup.

How can I proceed to enable access to my backend app? / How do I set the additionalLoginParams in auth version v2?

Comment: Parse your token.

Comment: Have you registered the front-end and back-end applications in Azure ad?

Comment: How do you set the `scope` or `resource`?

Comment: I've done everything according to the linked tutorial (except the very first part part about creating the app services as they were already created). So both apps are registered in AD and I set resource in loginParameters according to `["response_type=code id_token","resource=<back-end-client-id>"]`.

Comment: Can you parse your token?

Comment: Which token? The one with Graph API as audience? What would I look for?

Comment: Do not use graph api as the audience request token, because you did not call graph api. You should use your backend api as the audience request token.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I don't receive a token for my backend app, I only receive one for Graph API. Probably because I can't edit loginParameters, as my question states.

Comment: Are you saying that if you replace the client id of the **back-end api** application with **resource**, it will report an `AADSTS901002` error?

Comment: You need to make a small modification, change `"resource=ad402dxxxxxxxxxxx"` to `"scope={back-end api client id}/.default"`

Comment: I got `AADSTS901002` by setting `"loginParameters": ["response_type=code id_token","resource=<backend app id>"]`. Updating to `scope` according to your comment, gave me a new error: `{"code":401,"message":"An error of type 'unsupported_response_type' occurred during the login process: 'AADSTS700053: response_type 'id_token' requires the 'openid' scope.\r\nTrace ID: xxx\r\nCorrelation ID: xxx\r\nTimestamp: 2021-06-21 13:15:42Z'"}` from /.auth/login/aad/callback. Can't find much documentation on that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Add an `openid` :  `"scope=openid {back-end api client id}/.default"`

Comment: Note that there is a space after openid.

Comment: Thank you! This allowed me to access my frontend app. I still can't access my backend api through it though, getting `401 Unauthorized`. But I guess I'm gonna have to debug that separately, the token audience is my backend app now at least. Would you like to post a formal answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have a correct **access token**. Please note that I am not talking about **id token**. Because from your `response_type=code id_token`, there should be only one id_token returned, but obviously the id_token cannot call your api, because what you need is an access token.

If you have not obtained a correct access token, then you should request an access token in the next step, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#getting-access-tokens-silently-in-the-background).

In addition, I must explain that all **401 errors** are caused by api audiences. Therefore, make sure that your Application ID URI is set in the scope parameter.

When requesting an access token, you need to set the `scope` to: `scope=openid api://{back-end api client id}/.default`. Set `response_type` to: `response_type=token`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! If you edit your answer so that it is useful for someone who only read my original question but not our comments, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Anton  1. Remove the `api://` prefix    `scope=openid {back-end api client id}/.default`

 2. Provide me with a screenshot of your **expose an api**.

Comment: If you wish to help me with my further issue, I would appreciate that and I created a new question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68080981/getting-idx10205-when-accessing-backend-api-from-frontend. For this question I will accept your answer if you edit it so that it only contains an answer for my original question.