# Getting IDX10205 when accessing backend api from frontend

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to set up a frontend React app service and a backend Node app service, which both require authentication, according to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux).
I've followed the steps except that I needed to set `"loginParameters": ["response_type=code id_token", "scope=openid api://<backend app id>/user_impersonation"]` instead of `additionalLoginParams` since my app uses auth v2.

When my frontend app calls my backend api I get the following error

```
{"code":401,"message":"IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: '[PII is hidden]'."}
```

I don't know how to debug this as the useful information in the response is hidded and I can't find a way to show it when using Node. I have inspected the token and the issuer is `https://sts.windows.net/<tenant id>/`, but I don't know what's expected or how to set ValidIssuer.

What I do for authentication code-wise is calling `/.auth/me` from frontend after login to receive an access token and this token is passed to the backend api in the header as `Authentication: Bearer <access_token>`. I'm expecting Azure to handle everything else according to the settings made in the linked tutorial. Is this correct?

How can I debug this issue?

**EDIT**

This is how the Expose an API page of backend app registration looks.

[image]

This is the data of my access token.

[image]

Comment: There's a configuration setting which makes the PII hidden by default. You can change that setting to see this information in the error message.

Comment: @GauravMantri Where do I find this setting?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear earlier. Can you share the name and version of the SDK you're using for authentication/authorization? It's a setting in the SDK.

Comment: @GauravMantri I'm not using an SDK for authentication. I've restricted access from Azure portal and I call `/.auth/me` to get my token as mentioned in the question.

Comment: 1. Remove the `api://` prefix `scope=openid {back-end api client id}/.default` 2. Provide me with a screenshot of your **expose an api**.

Comment: Also, can you try with just a single scope - `api://<backend app id>/user_impersonation`? I read somewhere that using different multiple scopes does not work and the token will be fetched only for the 1st scope.

Comment: Neither `openid {back-end api client id}/.default` nor `api://<backend app id>/user_impersonation` made any difference. Updating my question to show expose api settings.

Comment: Can you parse the token and provide a screenshot?

Comment: @CarlZhao updated my question with token data

Comment: Very strange, why your token version is 1.0.

Comment: Set the `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion":2` in the application manifest.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#accesstokenacceptedversion-attribute

Comment: @CarlZhao That finally solved! I'm properly authenticated now! Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: I have posted it as an answer, and you can accept it to end the thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has been resolved, post it as the answer to the end of the question.

As I said in the comments, you need to obtain the `2.0` version of the token. So you need to change the [`accessTokenAcceptedVersion` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#accesstokenacceptedversion-attribute) of the application **manifest** to: `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2`.

Comment: Updating this property for the backend api was what solved it.