# How to authenticate a frontend SPA app and API when both use Azure Easy Auth

Tags: azure, oauth, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

**The situation**

I have a backend API and frontend SPA app both hosted in Azure. I have protected both these app services with Azure AD Easy Auth using the same app registration. This works - if I try and visit the frontend application I am redirected to the Microsoft login page where I can login and if I visit the API I am returned a 401 (I can login to it interactively via `/.auth/login/aad`). In both applications, I can visit `/.auth/me` to retrieve the `id_token` and `access_token` among other things. My SPA app will query this endpoint to retrieve the `id_token`. It then uses this token to communicate with the API via a Bearer token. This communication works and I can successfully call endpoints in this way.

The problem I am facing is that after some time, the `id_token` stored and sent by the frontend becomes invalid. I assumed the frontend would ask the use to login again which would refresh the `id_token` but this does not seem to be the case. I did some digging and apparently I should be sending the `access_token` up instead of the `id_token`. However, my API rejects that with:

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: '[PII is hidden]'. \nkid: '[PII is hidden]'. \nExceptions caught:\n '[PII is hidden]'.\ntoken: '[PII is hidden]'."
}
```

https://jwt.io also fails to verify the access token.

I am having a lot of trouble in finding resources/documentation for an SPA app and API which **both** use Easy Auth and how to get them to talk to each other.

**Things already tried**

- Removing any Microsoft Graph permissions from the app registration
- Changing the manifest "accessTokenAcceptedVersion" to `2` for the app registration
- Enabling both "ID tokens" and "Access tokens" for "Implicit grant and hybrid flows" for the app registration in the Azure portal
- Using cookie auth (sending up the cookie with requests from the SPA)
- Exposing an API and adding a permission for it

What is the standard way of authenticating a frontend and a backend when both are protected by Azure Easy Auth? Should I be using the `access_token` or `id_token` to authenticate? If the latter, how do I refresh it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are receiving access token for graph .
Please make sure scope is created for the backend web api .

> **Note**:User.Read is for graph api access and may have nonce in token
> generated  which may make  the signature invalidated for you web api.

So please create a new scope in the portal that identifies your backendapi i.e ; modify your app  to acquire an access token for your API.

1. Your spa App > `Expose an API` > Add Scope.
   (Create a new scope: say name = access_as_user)
2. In **API permissions**: Add a new permission for  registered application and  scope access_as_user. something like  `api://<app id>/ scope name`

Make sure you place this name of scope where ever you are using in your app scope ( remove user.read if present and add scope of your api) and **grant** admin consent .
Now try again and check the token in https://jwt.io .

If there is further error saying audience invalid:
Go to Manifest: Change entry "accessTokenAcceptedVersion" from (null or 1) to 2
And try .If not successful ,try by removing `api://` prefix from your app configuration scope.

**References:**

1. [Tutorial: Authenticate users E2E - Azure App Service | Microsoft
   Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux#enable-authentication-and-authorization-for-front-end-app)
2. [azure - Setting additionalLoginParams with auth v2 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68064936/setting-additionalloginparams-with-auth-v2)
3. [IDX10511 -issue (github.com)](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/1334#issuecomment-587050110)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this did not work. I have updated my question with some more information. Hope you (or someone else) can help!

Comment: I read your first reference again and picked up on some things that I missed. I had to ensure that I updated the "allowedAudiences" and the login scopes on resources.microsfot.com. I will accept your answer as that ultimately got me to the solution, but didnt contain all the info (highly recommend the first reference here)